# Issue with Update Spyder 4.2.0 in Anaconda

Tags: spyder

I'm using Python version 3.8 and try to update with Spyder 4.2.0.  I got a message, please see the attached image. Can anyone have the same issue and please share your solution?  Thank you!
Ben
[image]

Comment: use  sys.version to see your python version.  it may not be < 3.8.0a0

Comment: Never mind, I solved the issue above.  I used the commends: conda install python=3.7 then conda install spyder=4.2.0 then conda update spyder.  All the issue above solved!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue above using three commends below:

conda install python=3.7
conda install spyder=4.2
conda update spyder